# IntelliJでMavenのリポジトリでエラーになる

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Javaの入門をしようとIntelliJをはじめて使ってみました。基本的なプログラムは作れるようになったのですが、Mavenのリポジトリに登録されているパッケージを取得できないことに気づきました。

IntelliJの設定画面のRepositoriesを見てみたところ、ローカルもリモートもエラーになっています。どうしたら取得できるようになるのでしょうか? Macでインストールしました。

Comment: 質問に、エラー画面のスクリーンショットか、エラー内容のコピーを張るといろいろ早いですよ。 `Shift`+`⌘`+`4`で。またどのようにプロジェクトを作ったのか、 `pom.xml` はどうなっているかも重要です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます!
今使っているPCではうまく行っているせいでスクリーンショットが貼れません(もう一つのPCだけ問題となっています)。しかし単純にErrorとなっているだけで、その他に有用な情報がそこには表示されておらず困っています。
下にArtifactry or Nexus Service URLsというのがありますが、ここでテストをするとリポジトリが見つかったというメッセージが出ます。
pom.xmlには必要なパッケージを記述しています。正常に動作するPCではそこにパッケージを記述することで、自動的に取得処理が行われていました。

Comment: コンパイルがうまくいってない方のPCで、mvn compileを行うとどのようなエラーがでますか